# Random Number generation for each row

Tags: r

New to R coming from SAS...

I want to create a vector of 1,000 random numbers for each row using the function

```
runif(1,000, min = 0, max = 1)
```

and add it to my `data.frame`.

Trying this gives me the same number on each row:

```
EL$randoms <- runif(1, min = 0, max = 1)
```

How do I solve this simple problem?

Comment: What exactly is the output you're after? A data.frame with 1000 columns?

Comment: um... @Julius, I think you may have corrected the mistake in OP's question by removing the `,` in `runif(1,000...)`.. not sure though.

Comment: @joe, what's the problem with your first command? It gives you 1000 uniformly generated values...

Comment: Well, if you mix the first and the second line of code, you get the solution. But the second line of code is wrong, as only one value is assigned to a vector...

Comment: @Arun, it might be so, I put `,` back to make sure.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity and I pasted some confusing code.  I'm actually trying to get 1,000 random values for each observation.  The number of obs in the dataset may change.

Comment: Using this seemed to work (10 values here instead of 1,000): 
    EL$newrandoms<-matrix(data=runif(10*nrow(EL),min=0,max=1), nrow= nrow(EL), ncol=10)

Answer (score 6):

This way ?

```
EL$randoms <- runif(1000, min=0, max=1)
```

`El$randoms` is a whole column of your data frame. So you have to assign to it as many values as there are rows. With what you tried, only one random number was generated, and R, by its recycling rule, "repeats" it as many times as necessary to match the length of `EL$randoms`.

Comment: The OP has both the commands which makes it even more confusing.

Comment: +1 - @joe - First important thing I found coming from SPSS/SAS-like systems to R: Don't think row-by-row in datasets/data.frames. Most R functions are not intended to only create a single value, but rather work in a vectorised fashion to create all the values at once. e.g. - Don't create one random value 1000 times (once for each row), create 1000 random values once and assign them to the dataset.

Answer (score 6):

Super late to this party, but it came up in a Google search. Here is a way to assign a random number for every row in the data set without having to specify the exact number of rows.

```
EL$randoms <- runif(nrow(EL), min = 0, max = 1)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's the obligatory `tidyverse` answer using the popular newer syntax:

```
mtcars %>% 
    add_column(runif = runif(nrow(.)))
```